# Regex for matching some characters that should be left out later

Tags: regex, pcre

I will try to explain my situation with an example, consider the following string:

`03 - The-Basics-of-Querying-the-Dom.mov`

I need to remove all `-`s (hyphens) excluding the one after the digits. In other words, all *hyphens* in between the words.

This is the REGEX I created: `/([^\s])\-/`. But the problem is, when I try to replace, the character before the space is also removed.

Following the result I am aiming for:

`03 - The Basics of Querying the Dom.mov`

Think, I can use something like exclude groups? I tried to use `?:` & `?!` in the capture group to avoid it from being matched, but didn't give any positive results.

Comment: `/(?<=[a-z])-(?=[a-z])/gi`  https://regex101.com/r/pZ6tE2/1

Comment: `(?<!\d\s)-` https://regex101.com/r/pZ6tE2/2

Comment: Why not use [word boundaries](https://regex101.com/r/xB3pO8/2)

Comment: Can you add few more examples to make it clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just modified your already proposed RegEx by using a positive lookbehind (which only asserts the correct position):

```
/(?<=[^\s])\-/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
(?<=\w)-(?=\w)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yM5eC5/1)